# Doxygen: Interpret Template Argument Superclass

Tags: templates, doxygen

In this code, which is concatenated here for this example from multiple files in different libraries:

```
template <typename T1=void,typename T2=void,typename T3=void>
struct Implements ;

template <typename T1>
struct Implements<T1,void,void>
:   public virtual T1
{ } ;
template <typename T1,typename T2>
struct Implements<T1,T2,void>
:   public virtual T1
,   public virtual T2
{ } ;
template <typename T1,typename T2,typename T3>
struct Implements<T1,T2,T3>
:   public virtual T1
,   public virtual T2
,   public virtual T3
{ } ;

struct MySuper { } ;
struct MyClass : public Implements<MySuper> { } ;
```

How do I get doxygen to recognize that `MySuper` is a superclass of `MyClass`?

Currently, in the class list, it lists `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` as the superclass of that... sometimes. Other times it ignores it altogether.

I'm using `doxygen` version 1.8.4 (though 1.8.14 does not change this behavior).

The class diagram in this example shows Implements as deriving from [literally] `MySuper`, `T2`, and `T3`. (Note: this also indicates it doesn't understand partial template specialization and default arguments.) In my actual code, it often doesn't even show `MySuper` and shows `T1` instead.

Here's a diff between the `doxygen -g` file and my file:

```
28c28
< PROJECT_NAME           =
---
> PROJECT_NAME           = "MyLibrary"
41c41
< OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       =
---
> OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = generated
173c173
< TAB_SIZE               = 8
---
> TAB_SIZE               = 4
530c530
< WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
---
> WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = NO
571c571
< INPUT                  =
---
> INPUT                  = ../impl ../include
588c588
< FILE_PATTERNS          =
---
> FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c *.cpp *.cxx *.hxx *.hpp *.h *.dox
594c594
< RECURSIVE              = NO
---
> RECURSIVE              = YES
991c991
< GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
---
> GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
1308c1308
< GENERATE_TAGFILE       =
---
> GENERATE_TAGFILE       = generated/MyLibrary.tag
```

The `Implements` class is in MyLibrary, and the user code is in a different library. I have a similar doxy for the user project which differs primarily in

```
TAGFILES = ../../MyLibrary/docs/generated/MyLibrary.tag=../../../../MyLibrary/docs/generated/html
```

And in this case it does not expand the template arguments at all (it's verbatim `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` instead of 'MySuper', `T2`, and `T3`).

Comment: Which version of doxygen did you use? What are the settings in the Doxyfile different from the standard Doxyfile ?

Comment: @albert - Question updated with those details

Comment: Currently doxygen is at version 1.8.14, so please try with this version (1.6.1 is from 2009; RH is not known for quick updates of doxygen) as far as I can see it should work in version 1.8.14.

Comment: Ok, I just found that we have 1.8.4 available and just ran that. It understands now that Implements<> derives from T, but doesn't seem to know that MyClass derives from MySuper

Comment: You mention 1.8.4 (or is it a typo?). 1.8.4 is from (May) 2013, and since that time also a lot changed.

Comment: Sadly, it's not a typo; it is irritatingly difficult to get new software approved for use here.

Comment: I know that in some companies it is hard to get some new programs even just for testing. Maybe you could just do a local download and compilation.

Comment: @albert - I just tested it with the latest version of Doxygen's website with no significant change. However, the above simplified example works, but does not adequately represent the complexity of this system. I'm updating the question with a more accurate example.

Comment: I think that my knowledge about this implements is not sufficient. Best is to file a bug report in bugzilla (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen), possibly including current image / and required image. It might also be useful to set, temporary, in the Doxyfiel the EXTRACT_ALL etc. to YES (http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_extract_all).