# Doxygen & C++: Manually add parent class

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

I have a case where Doxygen fails to understand some templated code and inheritance (especially with template recursion and partial template specialization) and would like to tell Doxygen to *lie* about its superclass by manually specifying one. Ideally, something like this:

```
class MyClass
:   Implements<MySuper> //! \parent MySuper
{ } ;
```

My main problem is that Doxygen currently shows that class hierarchy as saying that `MyClass` derives from `Implements<MySuper>` which derives from `T0`, `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `T4`, `T5`, `T6`, `T7` ... (because those are the names of the template arguments) and loses the information that `MyClass` inherits from `MySuper`.

How do I convince Doxygen to lie?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006915/doxygen-interpret-template-argument-superclass ?

Comment: @albert - This is not a duplicate; this is a different question. The other question was how to get doxygen to correctly recognize that class hierarchy. This question is about me manually telling Doxygen to override its behavior.

Comment: I understand, as far as I can see/ know  there is no direct way to overrule this behavior, maybe something is possible my means of `#define` statements. Best is anyway also to file a bug report for the problem.